# How to add a class using jQuery, when I click on multiple elements

Tags: jquery

Given the following html:

```
<ul class="sub-categories">
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <h2 class="sub-header">
            <a href="">category name</a>
        </h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add the class 'current' to the 'a' tag inside '.sub-header' irrespective of which anchor is clicked.

The following works only when I click the first anchor.

```
$('ul.sub-categories li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).next(".sub-header").children('a').addClass("current");
});
```

How do I make it work irrespective of which anchor is clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$('ul.sub-categories>li').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.delegateTarget).find('h2>a').addClass("current");
});
```

http://jsbin.com/wajerujose/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.sub-categories li a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // works for first a clicked only        
    $(this).next(".sub-header").children('a').addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: works only for the first clicked element 'a', not for the second

Comment: @Marco So you want to add class to 'a' inside first .sub-header irrespective of which anchor is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub-categories li').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.sub-header a').addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: @Marco It's not probable I'd suggest you something that does not work: http://jsbin.com/tuqeyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output. Means you should show us more code. Or you have other listeners that are preventing the click to propagate or...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.sub-categories > li > a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();       
    $(this).next(".sub-header").find('a').addClass("current");
});
```

Main is to change the selector to `ul.sub-categories > li > a` from `ul.sub-categories li  a`. Because `ul.sub-categories li a` is acquiring all `<a>` within `.sub-categories`, while your target is only those `<a>` tags which are direct target to `ul.sub-categories li`.

Comment: works only for the first clicked element 'a', not for the second

Answer (score 0):

I did more research on this site and kept playing around and found something that works. Im not sure if it's the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
$('ul.sub-categories li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   if ($(this).parent().is(".sub-header")) {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else {
        $(this).next(".sub-header").children('a').addClass("current");
    }
});
```